Example of a non-Lie subgroup
We recently went over Ch. 7 of Lee's Smooth Manifolds in my differential topology class, and I was wondering what examples there are of subgroups of Lie groups which are not Lie subgroups.
I've seen posts claiming that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ in $\mathbb{R}^*$ is an example, but since a Lie subgroup is only required to be an immersed submanifold (by Lee's definition), I don't see how $\mathbb{Q}^*$ with the discrete topology would fail to be a Lie subgroup. Am I missing something? If not, is there an example of a subgroup of a Lie group that cannot be made into an immersed submanifold?

The additive group $\Bbb Q$ is not a Lie subgroup of $\Bbb R$, see this post: The rational numbers cannot be turned into a submanifold of the reals.

I saw that post, but it doesn't explain (at least to me) why it's not a Lie subgroup. From what I understand, the only thing that is shown is that $\mathbb{Q}$ not an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}$--I have no argument with that. But why is it not immersed?

Say a proper uncountable subgroup of $\mathbb R$? See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35970/construction-of-a-proper-uncountable-subgroup-of-mathbbr-without-choice for some examples.

@user8268 That does seem like it would work! Thanks!

What exactly do you mean when you say that a subgroup $H< G$ is not a Lie subgroup? Do you mean that there is no Lie group $L$ and an injective morphism $\phi: L\to G$ of Lie groups such that $\phi(L)=H$? Do you want to see examples when $G\ne \mathbb R$? Your comment to the existing answer only adds to the confusion.

@Moishe If $G$ is a Lie group, a Lie subgroup $H$ is defined (in Lee's Smooth Manifolds) to be a subgroup $H<G$ with a topology and smooth structure that makes it a Lie group and an immersed submanifold of $G$. So far, we have seen an example where the only topology and smooth structure making $H$ a Lie group precludes it from being an immersed submanifold because it not second countable. I am wondering if there are examples for which $H<G$ fails to be a Lie subgroup because it fails other conditions, such as having constant dimension or the inclusion map being an immersion.

Apologies, what I said about the "uncountable subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$" example was incorrect. The correct statement should be that $H$ fails to be a Lie group in the first place under the discrete topology.

The sentence "the only topology and smooth structure making
a Lie group precludes it from being an immersed submanifold because it not second countable." makes no sense to me (it does not parse even on the syntax level). Please, edit your question instead of replying in comments. As for the example of subgroups of $\mathbb R$: They are not Lie subgroups under any topology, not just the discrete one.

If Lie groups are not required to be second countable then every subgroup $H$ of any Lie group $G$ would be a Lie subgroup: take the discrete topology on $H$. Then $H$ is a $0$-dimensional manifold and therefore every map $H \to G$ an immersion.
If they should be second countable then the same holds for countable subgroups. In particular $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^* \subseteq \mathbb{R}^*$ are indeed Lie subgroups. So, you would be right with this definition.
If one requires Lie subgroups to be regular/embedded submanifolds, not just immersed, then $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^* \subseteq \mathbb{R}^*$ cannot be Lie subgroups since they otherwise would be discrete (as every countable manifold is discrete) and they are obviously no discrete subspaces.

This really helps clear things up for me for this example, thank you! I guess my next question would be whether there are any subgroups that fail to be Lie subgroups for other reasons. I was curious about the possibility of examples where the subgroup is locally Euclidean but of different dimensions at different points, or is a manifold by itself but the differential of the inclusion fails to be injective, etc.
